# jQuery Disable All Redirections (Links, Form Submissions, window.location changes etc)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, redirect

Is it possible to use javascript to disable **any code** that would take the browser away from the current page?

I have tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
$(window).unload(function(e){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I'm guessing this code doesn't work because by the time of unload(), it's too late.

Any other ideas?

Possible implementations:
1. disable any code that redirects
2. bind to all elements that can do this (links, forms, what else am i missing?)

Comment: Please consider the wisdom, and effects, of doing this. I know it'd annoy the hell out of me if I was browsing a website that prevented me leaving...having said that: +1 for an interesting question :)

Comment: @David Thomas, context. What if you were in the middle of editing something?

Comment: @jamietre, I accepted that there are (valid) reasons for doing this, as I accept the confirmation dialogue when I leave a page here on SO after starting to write an answer. My request he consider the "wisom [and] effects..." wasn't to imply that it shouldn't be done, just that it might not be the wisest thing to do.

Comment: Sure. With great power, comes great responsibility. I guess I am just giving him the benefit of the doubt, and I would be shocked to discover that anyone would ever want to try to prevent navigation for illegitimate reasons :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pop up a message in the browser asking the user if they wish to leave the page.  This works on every event that forces the browser to leave the current page (even form submissions and closing the browser).

Test Page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3937673/test.html

JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  var e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox (prior to 4)
  if (e){
    e.returnValue = 'Do you want to leave this page?';
  }
  // For Safari and Chrome
  return "Do you want to leave this page?";
};
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return "Do you want to leave this page?";
});
```

Comment: @user599146: It should work in Firefox also.  I could have sworn it works in Chrome too.

Comment: Does jQuery `bind()` to this event intelligently and deal with the browser differences? Always just done it the long way.

Comment: @jamietre: Yes it does.  I've tested in Firefox and Chrome, and it works.  Not sure about IE, it should work there too.

Comment: Also need to mention this does not work for pages that have inlined `window.location`. The redirect is automatic and immediate and the above prompt never comes up.

Comment: @greatwolf: Are you sure about that?  Check the [demo link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3937673/test.html) I have in the question.  The StackOverflow link has `onclick="location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'"`.

Comment: Ah I was also trying to get it to work with tampermonkey. Seems like it can't load the above code into the target page before it gets evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind it to all of the elements that may start it,

```
var stopLeaving = function(e){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?');
};

$('form').submit(stopLeaving);
$('a').click(stopLeaving);
```

Comment: Are there any other form elements that can cause the browser to go somewhere? While this solution works, is it possible to have a better solution that also stops javascript redirects?

Comment: No other elements that I can think of (but Im not thinking hard).

As for javascript redirects, im not sure. But it seems redundant to stop javascript redirects with javascript. Question is, why would you want to?

Comment: Binding to every link seems like overkill, `window.onbeforeunload` will stop anything from a hyperlink or javascript code. Heck it will stop you from shutting down the browser entirely. If the client is using some odd browser that doesn't support it then you're kind of SOL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$(window).unload(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

but it won't work.

quote from api.jquery.com:

> After this code executes, the alert will be displayed whenever the browser leaves the current page. It is not possible to cancel the unload event with .preventDefault(). This event is available so that scripts can perform cleanup when the user leaves the page.

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

so, the best you can do is to promt the user if he really wants to leave the page.

Comment: This is the same code that the OP posted in the question and says does not work.

Comment: no. in the example in the question the parameter "e" was passed and the methods .stopPropagation() and .preventDefault() were called on the variable "event" which doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: @user599146: please read my answer. it wont work because browsers won't let you do what you want to. and this completely makes sense. the unload() event is also fired if you close the window. you at least want to let the user do that. right?